# Write MySQL query to get expected result for test table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with MySQL database.

Table contains data like:

| id | uaid | attribute | value | time | risk factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | File Path | Exist | 16123 | NONE |
| 2 | 1234 | File Path | Not Exist | 16124 | CRITICAL |
| 3 | 1234 | File Path | Exist | 16125 | NONE |

the required result should be like below:

| Attribute | Risk Factor | UAID | Failed Value | Present Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| File Path | CRITICAL | 1234 | Not Exist | Exist |

**Explanation:**

1. we need to show data which have risk factor critical.
2. Failed Value =  at the time (latest one) when risk factor is critical then value for that attribute represent as failed value
3. Present value = it is represented as current value for that attribute in database.

i have tried with the solution of two sql queries. one for taking getting rows which have risk factor equal to critical. and the second one for getting current value of each unique attribuite. and then some formatting of data from the both queries.

I am looking for solution which removes the extra overhead of data formatting according to requirement.

**Schema** table(id,uaid,attribute,value,time,risk_factor)

Answer (score 0):

One option, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uaid, attribute
                                 ORDER BY time DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    attribute,
    'CRITICAL' AS `Risk Factor`,
    uaid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `risk factor` = 'CRITICAL' THEN value END) AS `Failed Value`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END) AS `Present Value`
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    attribute,
    uaid
HAVING
    SUM(`risk factor` = 'CRITICAL') > 0;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, 
i have a question. what if we have four types of risk ( critical , high , moderate , low ) and we have to perform same operation for rest of risk factors.
can you also provide changes for that ?

thanks for your response ;)

Comment: Once again, this is not the question you asked.

Comment: i am just putting a case nothing else :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a group is a rowset with the same `(uaid, attribute)` values:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
       attribute,
       'CRITICAL' `Risk Factor`,
       uaid,
       FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY uaid, attribute 
                                ORDER BY `risk factor` = 'CRITICAL' DESC, `time` DESC) `Failed Value`,
       FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY uaid, attribute 
                                ORDER BY `time` DESC) `Present Value`,
       SUM(`risk factor` = 'CRITICAL') OVER (PARTITION BY uaid, attribute) is_critical
FROM source_table
)
SELECT Attribute, `Risk Factor`, UAID, `Failed Value`, `Present Value`
FROM cte
WHERE is_critical;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8d37d39c98338c1249f386aa957f8ce)

Comment: Hi  Akina, i have a question. what if we have four types of risk ( critical , high , moderate , low ) and we have to perform same operation for rest of risk factors. can you also provide changes for that ? thanks for your response ;)

Comment: @uchihamadara Use according expression instead of current one for `is critical`. If you mean "get the same, but for groups which have no CRITICAL status row" then it is enough to use `WHERE NOT is_critical;`. For the most common solution you may use 4 separate expressions which counts the amount of rows for each separate status, and use complex condition in outer WHERE. *we have four types of risk ( critical , high , moderate , low )* For normalizing purposes they must be stored in separate table (or at least use ENUM datatype), additionally this allows to set their relative priority.