# Write a MySQL query to get required result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with MySQL database.

There are four types of risk factors Critical , High , Moderate , Low

Table contains data like:

| id | uaid | attribute | value | time | risk factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | Edge | Exist | 16123 | NONE |
| 2 | 1234 | Edge | Not Exist | 16124 | CRITICAL |
| 3 | 1234 | Edge | Exist | 16125 | NONE |
| 4 | 1237 | Chrome | Exist | 124745 | NONE |
| 5 | 1237 | Chrome | Not Exist | 124759 | HIGH |

the required result should be like below:

| Attribute | Risk Factor | UAID | Failed Value | Present Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Edge | CRITICAL | 1234 | Not Exist | Exist |
| Chrome | HIGH | 1237 | Not Exist | Not Exist |

**Explanation:**

1. we need to show data which have risk factor critical , moderate , high , low.
2. Failed Value =  at the time (latest one) when risk factor is critical then value for that attribute represent as failed value
3. Present value = it is represented as current value for that attribute in database.

i have tried with the solution of two sql queries. one for taking getting rows which have risk factor equal to critical. and the second one for getting current value of each unique attribuite. and then some formatting of data from the both queries.

I am looking for solution which removes the extra overhead of data formatting according to requirement.

**Schema** table(id,uaid,attribute,value,time,risk_factor)

Comment: Why you do not use [solution from previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66219124/10138734)? The only adjustment is in using ```FIND_IN_SET(`risk factor`, 'NONE,LOW,MODERATE,HIGH,CRITICAL')```.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match the shown result. If you want to show "data which have risk factor critical", why do you show data for UAID 1237? It doesn't have a CRITICAL row. Then, what is "current value" supposed to mean? How do you determine which row is "current"? Then, what does time = 16123 mean? This doesn't look like a time at all. Shouldn't that rather be something like 11:35, or even more precise something like 2021-02-10 11:35?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i have updated question you can look once again. and for  " How do you determine which row is current?"  basically every row has a time value which is epoch time . so simply which row has max time value that row is earliest one.

Comment: @Akina in the previous solution you are converting 'CRITICAL' in to column name Risk Factor .but this is not only the case

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to show "risk factor critical , moderate , high , low", why not simply show all the rows? It seems that per UAID you want to show the highest risk factor in the order of Critical, High, Moderate, Low. Is this so? The first four result columns taken from that row and the last column taken from the row with the highest epoch time?

Comment: And have you understood what Akina is refering to with `FIND_IN_SET`? This gives you the sort key you need for that risk factor ranking. You can apply this to the query Akina has given you. And why haven't you accepted Akina's answer on your original request?

Comment: *in the previous solution you are converting 'CRITICAL' in to column name Risk Factor .but this is not only the case* In previous question you needed in to extract the rows for one state only, so literal value could be used. For all state values you need according FIRST_VALUE, and I give you adjustment/sorting expression.

Comment: If there's a 1 to 1 correlation between uaid and attribute then this should be recorded in a separate table

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want last value that is one of the four that you specify (i.e. not `'NONE'`).  Window functions are probably the simplest solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(value) over (partition by uaid order by id desc) as current_value
      from t
     ) t
where risk_factor <> 'NONE';
```